# How do you say "with style" in German?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

The singer of Oasis sings with style.

> Der Sänger von Oasis singt mit Stil.

Is *mit Stil* correct in this context? Can I also use *stilisch*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"mit Stil" or "sehr stilvoll" are both possible. I'm not sure though if in English the phrase "with style" also has a strong connotation to elegant, as it does in German.

"stilisch" is not a proper German word. You either mean the English word "stylish" that is used a lot by young Germans or the word "stilistisch", which would translate to "stylistic".